# "In addition to" synonyms specific to scientific writing?

Tags: formality, tone

I'm tired of using the same expression in scientific academic papers over and over again...

But I can't find any formal equivalent synonyms to "In addition to" besides **additionally to**...

Do you have any nice suggestions?

Does **beyond** fits in this type of writing?

Example phrase:

Beyond having similar osmosis potential to polymer sponges, it is desirable that the covering material possesses the ability of being dispersed by the environment while being continuously replaced by the structure beneath

I've came across some synonyms too:

**as well as - aside from - besides - including**

But do they fit in a scientific academic writing tone?

I'm just not familiarized in seeing it on google scholar papers for example...

It's just my impression then? Can I use them with no problems? Any of them fit well in my example phrase?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Additionally", "furthermore", "also", "moreover", "conjointly", "likewise", "not to mention".

Comment: Thanks!! But see, of your examples, only "Additionally" fits in my example phrase I think, right? With this meaning that I need